# Android HttpPost request not posting

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http-post, httpclient, blobstore

I'm attempting to send a POST request from within an Android app to my Google App Engine app in order to upload a file to the blobstore and some metadata to the Datastore.  I built a regular webform which I can access from a browser, and posting from there works just fine.  However, I haven't been able to do the same from my Android app.

A lot of other StackOverflow posts mention the use of `MultipartEntity` or `MultipartEntityBuilder` to build the post request.  The former seems to be deprecated but there are more examples of it, so I tried both ways (separately, of course):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(upload_url);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addTextBody("poem_name", "Testing poem_name from Android", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
builder.addTextBody("poem_text", "blah", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
postRequest.setEntity(builder.build());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
HttpEntity theEntity = response.getEntity();
theEntity.consumeContent();
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

and

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(upload_url);                        
StringBody poem_name = new StringBody("Testing poem_name from Android");
StringBody poem_text = new StringBody("blah");
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("poem_name", poem_name);
entity.addPart("poem_text", poem_text);
postRequest.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

The original webform, which works like a charm from a regular browser, looks like this in my template (I omitted the file upload initially in the Android code, as that weas too problematic to debug right away):

```
<form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Poem Title: <input name="poem_name" required><br>
  Poem Text:<br><textarea name="poem_text" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
  Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Poem">
</form>
```

However, when I execute either of the top two sections of code on my Android app, nothing shows up on my server.  The upload_url that's passed into the HttpPost constructor is the very same one that's used in the action field of the web form `{{ upload_url }}` (it's dynamically generated by Google App Engine).  So, I thought I'd try posting to any web form, not one that requires multipart entities and dynamic URLs.  I built a new barebones web form on a different page of the app, like so...

```
<form action="/testForm" method="post">
  <input name="nickname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Create Test Entity">
</form>
```

...and attempted a basic post request as seen in numerous beginner examples:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://my-app-title.appspot.com/testForm");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", "test with NameValuePair"));
postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Sure enough, the form works great in a browser but produces no result when executing this code from my Android app (not even null values in place of the "nickname" field, which tells me that the issue lies in the post request not getting executed for some reason).  By all accounts that I've read, this ought to work.  Is there something I'm forgetting which isn't allowing me to complete the post request?  I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: did you consider looking at the response to see if the server has anything to say about your request?

Comment: or is there anything at all in the logs on the android side? are you catching exception and not logging them?

Comment: Hi njzk2, thanks for the reply!  Looking at the actual httpresponse proved to be really helpful.  I'll type up an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Per njzk2's suggestion, I used an InputStream to look at the content of the HttpResponse.  For reference, this is the code I used:

```
InputStream iStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
while ((tempString = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    postResponseOutput += tempString;
}
Log.d("HttpResponse Output", postResponseOutput);
```

For the barebones form, I made the mistake of requiring a login on the url at /testForm, so Google's sign-in page was returned rather than my form.  Removing that restriction made the form work perfectly.

Trying it with the `MultipartEntityBuilder` section of my code returned something interesting in the post response, nothing more than "The request's content type is not accepted on this URL".  But trying it with the `MultipartEntity` section seemed to do the trick.  The httpresponse returned an internal server error (something to do with user authentication).  That explains why posting to the original webform wasn't working - there was a server error preventing the form from being accessed in the first place.  I trust that once I resolve the error that the form will work just as well as it did for my testForm.

Comment: as a side note: the difference between your multipartEntity and your multipartEntityBuilder is the contenttype of the StringBody: In the first case you specify `ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`, in the second case, you don't, and the default value is `"text/plain"`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Is there a benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: builder vs non-builder? not really. the builder follows the builder pattern, which allows you to chain the calls. that is really only about what you prefer to use. behind the scene, the builder is really just calling the same methods.